# Creating a tag does create a forke and leads to a warning message on GitHub

Tags: git, github

I recently bumped the version of a software on GitHub. I did it by first fixing a bug with a commit, and then bumping the version of the software again with a commit. Then I created a tag for this last commit and pushed this tag to GitHub. This, however, created a surprise as I got a warning on GitHub that said

```
This commit does not belong to any branch on this repository, and may belong to a fork outside of the repository.
```

Why is that? I found some people having the same issues, for example [This commit does not belong to any branch on this repository, and may belong to a fork outside of the repository.](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/45642) However, I do not understand what they are saying, and also not why it happens.

Here is the sequence of commands that lead to it.

```
git add setup.py
git commit -m "fix(setup): issue #123"
git push origin

git add my_package/__init__.py setup.cfg
git commit -m "build(version): bump"
git tag v3.1.1
git push origin v3.1.1
```

I expected that when I push the tag, that then also the last commit gets pushed to the main branch and the tag points to it. But this did not happen. Why?

Here are the first eight lines output of `git log --decorate --graph --all --oneline`

```
* 2c77966 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) bump version
| * 14ab665 (tag: v1.3.1) build(version): bump
|/  
* 8ce7bc9 bla
* 46868f7 bla
* 22928dc bla
* 9012092 bla
* 18cdd7e bla
* f40ee30 bla
```

Comment: Try pushing the last commit, too.

Comment: @choroba I tried, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You pushed the tag, and yes the commit goes with it, but you did not push the change to the branch.

Branches in Git work very differently than other version control systems. Branches are merely labels which point at the latest commit in a branch. A commit does not belong to a branch, we refer to commits as being referrable by branches and tags.

```
m [branch2]
. .
.  .
l   k [branch1]
.  .
. .
.
j
.
i
```

In this example, commit k is referrable by branch1 and branch2. Commit k is also currently the head of branch1.

---

Your local repo looks like this.

```
C [somebranch] [v3.1.1]
.
B
.
A
.
.
.
```

And because you pushed only the tag, not the changes to the branch, Github's copy of your repo looks like this.

```
C [v3.1.1]
.
B [somebranch]
.
A
.
.
.
```

The branch is at the previous commit from your last `git push`. Github thinks the v3.1.1 commit is not part of any branch.

You can solve this by pushing the branch. `git push` will push the current branch to its remote.

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing happens when I do `git push`. It says `Everything up-to-date`. I think I start to understand what happened thanks to your explanation, but I'm unsure if I really do, In any case, it is definitely not a behavior I expected.

Comment: @MacOS Git is one of those programs where you have to understand it to really use it, and unfortunately `git log` (by default) and Github both show a harmful over simplification. Show us `git log --decorate --graph --all --oneline` please. That will show the true state of the repo. The first 10 lines or so should do, it should show your tag, your branch, and their origin/... versions. Edit that info into your question

Comment: Thank you for the command! I added a simplified output.

Comment: @MacOS You somehow made a branch. 1) Where did the `bump version` commit come from? 2) Where is the `fix(setup)` commit? 3) Are you *sure* those are all the commands you ran? `history` will tell.